# What link references to include when setting up foundation project in phpStorm

Tags: zurb-foundation

Firstly I am new to using foundation.

When you go onto foundations website and you download the complete foundation file you get this index file:

[image]

[image]

that has link references to the stylesheets and the Js files  and if you start coding everything works just fine, but if I create a foundation project through php storm it downloads the foundation release straight from GitHub, but this folder:

[image]

[image]

does not have a index file that includes the required css and js files, and I have tried to find the files but they are not included in this version from github. What files do I need to link to get foundation working.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you'd need to link foundation.min.css and foundation.min.js. also, make sure you include jquery before the js.

I suggest downloading a bundle from Zurb's site [in this link](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) and recieve a good and working bundle.

Foundation is a great framework so don't give up, it's totally worth it.